# Empty man pages after upgrade to Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: man, kubuntu

When I run the command

```
$ man ls
```

all it shows me is

```
Manual page ls(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit)
```

and after pressing q

```
man: command exited with status 4: (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim) | (cd /usr/share/man && /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE) | (cd /usr/share/man && preconv -e UTF-8) | (cd /usr/share/man && tbl) | (cd /usr/share/man && nroff -mandoc -rLL=204n -rLT=204n -Tutf8)
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it was related to the problem, but the answer below helped me:

https://askubuntu.com/a/763984/572615

I had to execute the suggested commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub\*
sudo apt-get install grub-efi
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I can't see how reinstalling the bootloader can fix the manpage database. I think it's more likely that the system was updating the manpage database in the background while you were accessing it, making the output garbled.

Comment: @Mioriin It is unlikely. I've tried to view man pages at different times with the same result.